# How to Create a button for change page?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a form in a html file inside my google apps script project, I need to redirect to another html file when a submit button is Clicked.

HTML CODE:

```
 <html>
      <script>
        function doSomething(){
          alert('this one works too!'); 
          //here Change of page
        }
      </script>

     <body>
        <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:Tahoma;">HORAS LABORADAS<br/>    
        <form style="margin-left:90px;font-family:Trebuchet MS;">
          <b>Nombre</b><br/>
          <input type="button" onclick="doSomething()">
        </form>
      </body>
 </html>
```

I call this by

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('prueba').evaluate();
}
```

Comment: Remember that I'm work in google-apps-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML FILE1

```
      <html>
          <body>
            <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:Tahoma;">HORAS LABORADAS<br/>    
            <form style="margin-left:90px;font-family:Trebuchet MS;">
              <b>Nombre</b><br/>
              <?var url = getUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=2'><input type='button' name='test' value='GO TO PAGE 2'></a>
            </form>
          </body>
     </html>
```

HTML FILE2

```
<html>
  <h1>This is Page 2.</h1><br/>
 <?var url = getUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=1'>  <input type='button' name='test' value='RETURN TO PAGE 1'></a>
</html>
```

CODE.GS

```
function getUrl(){
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}

 function doGet(requestInfo) {
      var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
      if (requestInfo.parameter && requestInfo.parameter['page'] == '2') {
        return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('FILE2').evaluate();
      }
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('FILE1').evaluate();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to redirect to another page, use the following:

```
<script>
    function doSomething(){
      alert('this one works too!'); 
      window.location.href = "http://myurl.com";
    }
</script>
```

Source: [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: I want to redirect to another file that I create!!

Comment: just replace the URL with the name of your file and ensure that your file and the file with the form code in it are in the same directory.

Comment: It doesn't work... remember that i'm work in google-apps-script